# Executing scripts from html using php

Tags: javascript, php, python, html

i have the follwing HTML with javascript calling a PHP file

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething() {
       $.get("mySample.php");
       return false;
     }
 </script>
 <body class="page_bg">
 <a href="#" onclick="doSomething();">Click Me!</a></head>
 </body>
 </html>
```

when it is executed it should call up "mySample.php" script, whose code is given below

```
 <?php
 #if ($_GET['run']) 
 {
  # This code will run if ?run=true is set.
   exec("python visualization.py");
 }
 ?>
```

then this piece of code calls up the python script called visualization.py, which results in some.html file, which i want to get back in the browser.

1. Given above approach is not working
2. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display your data when you call you need to handle the response you're getting. I think this will work:

```
$.get("mySample.php", function(resp){
    $('body').html(resp);
});
```

And have you tested if your php file works?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$.get( "mySample.php", function(data) {
  $('body').html(data);
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

More detail: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/